# Opensource, noncommercial License?

Tags: licensing

i want to publish my software under a opensource license with the following conditions:

you are allowed to:

- Share — to copy, distribute and
  transmit the work
- use a modified
  version of the code in your
  application

you are not allowed to:

- publish modified versions of the code
- use the code in anything commercial

is there a software license out there that fits my needs ?

Comment: this is more for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why would you publish open source code, but not let people publish modifications to your code? I doubt there's a license that covers this. Also, this is DEFINITELY not "open source".

Comment: Also, you let users use, but not publish, modified versions of your code? What's the point of that?

Comment: crosspost: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32444/opensource-noncommercial-license

Comment: the point is that this way i can decide whether somebody is allowed to publish his version. So i can assure the quality of the modified versions. And no it is open source since you can read the source ...

Comment: [a canonical definition of open source](http://www.opensource.org/docs/osd)

Comment: Being able to read the code is not considered open source, being able to modify and re-publish the code is. Microsoft has a license for Windows source code that educational institutions can apply for so any student anywhere can study Windows source code. Is Windows open source?

Comment: Should not be closed. This is **not** off-topic Licensing issues are directly related to software development. And no, licensing questions belong here, not programmers.stackexchange. A license, like a piece of code, have very well-defined meanings and cannot in any way be considered subjective and argumentative.

Comment: Questions about software license are expressly allowed on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: this is a relevant question. why closed?

Comment: https://opensource.org/licenses/NPOSL-3.0 might not be OSI approved but seems to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish code under any licence you want but it will only be F/OSS, Open Source, if it complies with the OSI definition : http://www.opensource.org/docs/osd. Your conditions are incompatible in several ways.

Take note that almost all players in Open Software use OSI-compliant licences - you would be going completely against all current opinion and practice.

Answer (score 2):

Having a noncommercial clause is against the spirit of opensource. So no, there isn't. And if you do make one yourself then you should not be calling it opensource but instead call it a non-commercial license.

There are in fact code with the kind of licensing you are talking about and there are widely recognised by the opensource community as being non-opensource. MINIX (by Tanenbaum) is one of them. The code is freely available and public and anyone can see but have severe restrictions on re-publishing modifications. MINIX is widely considered to be a closed-source piece of code.

Lots of commercial, proprietay, closed-source embedded operating systems are actually distributed as code and have only copyright laws protecting them (instead of complex, byzantine DRM). Just the fact that people can see your source code does not make it open source.

One last example. Windows (including XP, Vista and Seven). Microsoft makes the source code Windows available to anyone who needs it for non-commercial, educational purposes provided you sign an NDA. Their source license sounds a lot like what you want. Check out the license here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/licensing/basics/wrklicense.mspx. I doubt anyone would argue that Windows is opensource.

Comment: well, GPL allows you to use in commercial app, but you must release sources. how can you sell something that is free? so noncommercialism is not against opensource at all.

Comment: @Andrey: On the contrary. GPL does not restrict you from selling your product and having such restriction is against the spirit of GPL. Lots of people sell GPL licensed software: RedHat, Linksys, Netgear, Nokia, Motorola, Trolltech etc.

Comment: @Andrey: Further, GPL does not require you to release the sources to the world. It only requires you to release them to your customer(s) and you are required to allow them to republish that code without restriction. If that customer does not want to republish then nobody else gets to see that code.